# Significance of a group answer to a question

Tags: probability

I ask a group of 100 people a question to which each individual either agrees, disagrees or cannot answer - e.g. 70/100 agree, 10/100 disagree and 20/100 have no opinion. Is there any statistical test I can apply to give the probability that the correct answer is to agree with the question?

Comment: What connection is there between the "correct" answer and these frequencies?

Answer (score 2):

No--not formally, at least.  The logic of significance testing goes like this:
a) We posit that if chance -- some random process -- were at work, we would see results that could be described by some distribution such as a bell curve, a flat "rectangular" distribution, a "binomial" (this or that) distribution, etc., depending on the situation.
b) Given a set of results we obtain, we ask how unusual it would be for the random process to produce such results.

In your example, you have identified no underlying distribution with which to compare the results you obtained.

On the other hand, and less formally, there is a tradition of using the guesses of large numbers of people in order to estimate the correct amount of something.  By this tradition, the guesses of hundreds of people, averaged out, should approximate an amount such as the number of jelly beans in a bowl. Perhaps someone can locate a good reference for this, or some cleverer examples.

Comment: +1 nice rolando2 (as usual).  This is a productive answer to a question that makes productive answers difficult to give.

Answer (score 1):

As stated, no.  The reason is that you don't know the probabilities that the individual respondents are correct.

If you knew, for example, that each respondent had a 25% chance of being correct, independent of each other, and 70/100 agreed, and you were willing to assign a prior probability of, say, 50% to the correctness of agreeing, then you could calculate a posterior probability that agreeing was correct, in this case a number in the vicinity of $10^{-19}$.  A 51% chance of each respondent being correct and independent responses would give you a posterior probability of about 83% that agreeing was correct $\left(=\frac{0.51^{40}}{0.51^{40}+0.49^{40}}\right)$.